# When clicking a button app kills process

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, uiviewcontroller, unrecognized-selector

Basically I've created a soundboard app from another app. However i keep getting the same error and I can't understand whats wrong. I'm quite new to xcode and I've searched all over the internet for help. I'll post all information which maybe required and hopefully can get this working.

### ## The Error Report ##

```
2011-04-27 00:37:01.437 SoundBoard[11613:207] -[HBFSViewController pushBetter]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x693ccb0
2011-04-27 00:37:01.440 SoundBoard[11613:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[HBFSViewController pushBetter]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x693ccb0'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02553b99 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x026a340e objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x025556ab -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x024c52b6 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x024c4e72 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   UIKit                               0x002b27f8 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    6   UIKit                               0x0033dde0 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x00340262 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    8   UIKit                               0x0033ee0f -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
    9   UIKit                               0x002d63d0 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
    10  UIKit                               0x002b7cb4 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
    11  UIKit                               0x002bc9bf _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7672
    12  GraphicsServices                    0x02e33822 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x02534ff4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x02495807 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x02492a93 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x02492350 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x02492271 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x02e3200c GSEventRunModal + 217
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x02e320d1 GSEventRun + 115
    20  UIKit                               0x002c0af2 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    21  SoundBoard                          0x00001b30 main + 102
    22  SoundBoard                          0x00001ac1 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
## HBFS VIEW CONTROLLER .M ##

import "HBFSViewController.h"
import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>

@implementation HBFSViewController

- (IBAction)pushAbout {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"About" message:@"The Mr Dolan Soundboard : Created by Charlie Gilbertson" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

}

- (IBAction)pushAnd {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"And" ofType:@"aif"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];    

}

- (IBAction)pushLad {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Lad" ofType:@"aif"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];

}

- (IBAction)pushNoLegs {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"No legs" ofType:@"aif"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];

}

- (IBAction)pushMyDaughter {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"My Daughter" ofType:@"aif"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];

}

- (IBAction)pushLass {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Lass" ofType:@"aif"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];

}

- (IBAction)pushYO {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YO" ofType:@"aif"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];

}

- (IBAction)pushTape {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Tape" ofType:@"aif"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];    

}

- (IBAction)pushMySon {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"My Son" ofType:@"aif"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];

}

- (IBAction)pushNoArms {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"No arms" ofType:@"aif"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];

}

- (IBAction)pushCanDo {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Can do better than you" ofType:@"aif"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];

}

- (IBAction)pushOr {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Or" ofType:@"aif"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];

}

- (IBAction)pushScotch {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Scotch" ofType:@"aif"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];

}

- (IBAction)pushAndThey {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"And they've got" ofType:@"aif"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];

}

- (IBAction)pushEgg {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Egg" ofType:@"aif"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];

}
@end


## HBFS VIEW CONTROLLER .H ##

import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>

@interface HBFSViewController :UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *aboutButton;
    IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolBar;
}
- (IBAction)pushAbout;
- (IBAction)pushAnd;
- (IBAction)pushLad;
- (IBAction)pushLass;
- (IBAction)pushOr;
- (IBAction)pushScotch;
- (IBAction)pushTape;
- (IBAction)pushYO;
- (IBAction)pushEgg;
- (IBAction)pushNoLegs;
- (IBAction)pushNoArms;
- (IBAction)pushMyDaughter;
- (IBAction)pushMySon;
- (IBAction)pushCanDo;
- (IBAction)pushAndThey;
@end
```

Answer (score 3):

See this error message?

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[HBFSViewController pushBetter]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x693ccb0
```

Now look at all the `IBAction` methods you've listed (`-pushAbout`, etc.).

You'll notice that `-pushBetter` is not listed among them.

You need to write a `-pushBetter` method and wire it up to the `UIButton`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're somehow sending a pushBetter method call to your view controller which it is apparently not prepared for (according to your code and the error):

```
-[HBFSViewController pushBetter]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x693ccb0'
```

Can you to a global search for "pushBetter" and see where it is in your project??